# Compose Navigation: How to use a ModalBottomSheetLayout as a navigation destination

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, android-jetpack-navigation

Is it possible to use a `ModalBottomSheetLayout` as a navigation destination when using the AndroidX Navigation Compose library?

Currently the library support composables and dialogs as destination but I'm not sure if and how can it be used to have a modal bottom sheet as destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library `com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-material` can be used to achieve this.

1. Add the dependency to your module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-material:<version>"
}
```

2. Create a `BottomSheetNavigator` and add it to the `NavController`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    val bottomSheetNavigator = rememberBottomSheetNavigator()
    val navController = rememberNavController(bottomSheetNavigator)
}
```

3. Wrap your `NavHost` in the `ModalBottomSheetLayout` composable that accepts a `BottomSheetNavigator`.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    val bottomSheetNavigator = rememberBottomSheetNavigator()
    val navController = rememberNavController(bottomSheetNavigator)
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(bottomSheetNavigator) {
        NavHost(navController, Destinations.Home) {
           // We'll define our graph here in a bit!
        }
    }
}
```

4. Register a bottom sheet destination

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    val bottomSheetNavigator = rememberBottomSheetNavigator()
    val navController = rememberNavController(bottomSheetNavigator)
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(bottomSheetNavigator) {
        NavHost(navController, Destinations.Home) {
           composable(route = "home") {
               ...
           }
           bottomSheet(route = "sheet") {
               Text("This is a cool bottom sheet!")
           }
        }
    }
}
```

[Documentation](https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-material/) and [sample](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/sample/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/sample/navigation/material).

Comment: so why navigation compose does not support bottomsheets